Pass 404 response from Apache backend through Nginx reverse proxy
I'm running a Rails application with Apache and mod_passenger with an Nginx front-end for serving static files. For this most part this is working great and has been for years.
I'm currently making some improvements to the error pages output by the Rails app and have discovered that the Nginx error_page directive is overriding the application output and serving the simple static HTML page specified in the Nginx config.
I do want this static HTML 404 page returned for static files that don't exist (which is working fine), but I want to handle application errors with something nicer and more useful for the end user.
If I return the error page from the Rails app with a 200 status it works fine, but this is obviously incorrect. When I return the 404 status the Rails-generated error page is overridden.
My Nginx configuration is pretty typical (irrelevant parts removed):
error_page 404 /errors/not-found.html;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host              $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Sendfile-Type   X-Accel-Redirect;
}


I tried setting proxy_intercept_errors off; in the aforementioned location block but it had no effect.
I'm running Nginx 1.18.0 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Nginx will not intercept errors from upstream unless proxy_intercept_errors is on. Check full config with  nginx -T.

I both grepped the contents of /etc/nginx and the output from nginx -T and the intercept directive is nowhere to be seen. It should be off by default so I'm puzzled why it's intercepting those Apache 404 responses.
